# Is www.lirik.live/soal-https-stackoverflow.com a phishing site?

Tags: discussion, phishing

I accidentally hit this question from Google Search (written in code on purpose to prevent others to open it) while logged in on SO.

```
https://www.lirik.live/soal-https-stackoverflow.com/questions/72185081/hide-show-parameters-based-on-a-condition-in-azure-devops-pipelines-yaml#
```

After a while, I noticed I wasn't logged and was about to enter the credentials, but luckily I double checked by chance since the browser could not auto complete the login.

I am not sure I can do what is stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do) since to me this is also able to capture the credentials since it owns the domain. What should I do?

Comment: [meta.se] duplicate candidate: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do) From your description, this sounds like a proxy.

Comment: it is... that's means I have to apologize, as it was clearly written in the link I have provided. I report the site. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do

Comment: This site is redirecting me to another site which is blocked by uBlock Origin.

Comment: Doh! I was testing an app in a plain chrome instance.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.